# Target CSS with different attribute values?

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, attributes

I have a click btn that will dynamically select the data-attr values from the html.

```
$(".template-seasonFinder li a[data-season=seasonX]").css("display","block");
```

and I have a variable called `seasonX` that store `data-season` values, but adding the variable within the selector wont work.

How can I make it's value dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to build the selector:

```
$('.template-seasonFinder li a[data-season="' + seasonX + '"]')
```

Comment: Simple string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

You can turn everything into a variable.

```
yourvar = ".template-seasonFinder li a[data-season=" + seasonX + "]";
$(yourvar).css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

An other possible solution is by using the `filter` method ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)):

```
var winter = "summer"; //Adjusting for global warming
$('.template-seasonFinder li a').filter( function( i, e ) {
  return $(this).data( 'season' ) == winter;
} );
```